# 'Connection' word meaning in Java JDBC syntax

Tags: java, jdbc, connection, database-connection

I am new to Advanced JAVA concepts and I'm going through JDBC basics. 
In creating a connection object the syntax is

```
public static Connection getConnection(String url,String name,String password)
```

throws SQLException

I know that `public` is an access specifier, `static` is a keyword, `getConnection()` is a method name, the content inside the parentheses are parameters for the method, and the 'throws SQL exception' is used for raising exception. But

1. what is 'Connection' there?
2. why did the word 'Connection' get over there?
3. Isn't it against to the rule of general JAVA syntax, i.e. `access_specifier other_keywords return_type method_name(parameters_type parameters_list)`

Comment: `Connection` is the `return_type`. You've answered your own question. Question (2) is the same as (1), and the answer to (3) is 'no'.

Answer (score 1):

1. Because the method returns an **instance** of the class [`java.sql.Connection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html)
2. Because it's the class name of the instance returned by the method
3. No. It's the return type of the method. The class `java.sql.Connection`.
4. Limit your question to **ONE** question please.
5. See also [`java.sql.SQLException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html)

Somewhere near the top you have `import java.sql.*;` or the two mentioned classes explicitly imported. Thus you don't have to type `java.sql` everytime you mean `java.sql` (but that's because of the unshown import(s)).

Comment: Hi Elliot, Thanks for your answer.
1. But I see that the getConnection() method is a method from the DriverManager class. In that case, is Connection class a parent class to DriverManager class?
4. Sorry for that, I'm new to this website. Thanks, I'll follow it from my next question.

Comment: [A third java.sql class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html). Read your import statements/javadocs.